# Call multiple dictionaries who names involve i in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to call multiple dictionaries using a for loop. I am unsure how to call multiple dictionaries properly, and I can't figure out if its possible using concatenation. The code below should explain my thinking even though the print statement is incorrect.

```
stat0 = {}
stat0["bob"] = 0
stat1 = {}
stat1["bob"] = 0
stat2 = {}
stat2["bob"] = 0

for i in range(3):
    print(stat(i))
```

Comment: Did any answer answered you question?

Comment: Hint: see how you already handle the problem of using `"bob"` to get information from `stat0`? What if you *used the same technique* to organize `stat0`, `stat1` and `stat2`?

Answer (score 2):

How about putting them in a collection, and then getting value generically:

```
for hm in [stat0, stat1, stat2]
    print(hm["bob"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming your dictionaries, just put them into another dictionary:

```
#UNTESTED
stat = { 0: stat0, 1: stat1, 2: stat2 }
for i in range(3):
    print(stat[i])
```

Or, use an iterative style more appropriate for `dict`:

```
#UNTESTED
for i, d in stat.items():
    print(i, d)
```